# Using gitlab-vagrant-vm from OSX host

Tags: vagrant, gitlab

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-vagrant-vm) and was able to succesfully (I think) install the gitlab vagrant virtual machine on OSX 10.8 using virtualbox.

I can do `vagrant up` to get the VM running, and everything seems to work fine. After that I can do `vagrant ssh` without a problem. Also, after sshing into the VM I was able to do `bundle exec rake gitlab:test`, which completed with results being `1584 examples, 0 failures`.

I would like to see the gitlab web interface from my OSX host machine. I thought I could just direct my browser to the IP indicated in the VagrantFile (`http://192.168.3.14`), but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Also any other usage tips for this setup would be appriciated (things like where the repositories are stored on my host machine so I can back them up, if anyone set the gitlab-vagrant-vm up for external access from either another computer on the network or a remote source, ect.)

Comment: hey @spencerlyon2 it would be really nice to address both questions below and to let the guys know if their answers helped or not.. you gotta give and take at SO

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect a second interface for vagrant. To do this you've to edit the VagrantFile.
For example if you want to conenct to the host wifi add the following line after `192.168.3.14`

```
config.vm.network :bridged, bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
```

You also can bridge to the ethernet interface. Use `ifconfig` on the host machine to determine the right interface. After that the dyndns-server of the host network will assign an IP to the Vagrant-Box. Then you can access GitLab on that IP.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually start the server?  You can do that with

```
bundle exec foreman start -p 3000
```

This will start the server on port 3000, you would then access it from the host with

```
http://192.168.3.14:3000/
```

Hope this helps,

Chris